# Heroku: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503

Tags: express, heroku

My www file in the express module is

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('ilovearistiserver:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
//var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '5000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 *
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('App is running on port ' + port);
});
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string' ? 'Pipe ' + port : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string' ? 'pipe ' + addr : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

My package.json is

```
{
  "name": "ilovearistiapi",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.13.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1"
  }
}
```

Next, I uploaded my express app in Heroku.

```
Theodosioss-MacBook-Pro:iLoveAristi-api theodosiostziomakas$ git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 37, done.
Counting objects: 100% (37/37), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (31/31), done.
Writing objects: 100% (37/37), 11.89 KiB | 2.38 MiB/s, done.
Total 37 (delta 12), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:        

remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  12.13.0
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:        
remote:        Resolving node version 12.13.0...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 12.13.0...
remote:        Using default npm version: 6.12.0
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules
remote:        added 100 packages in 1.83s
remote:        
remote: -----> Build
remote:        
remote: -----> Caching build
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        
remote: -----> Pruning devDependencies
remote:        audited 101 packages in 1.054s
remote:        found 4 vulnerabilities (3 low, 1 critical)
remote:          run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
remote:        
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 22.3M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v3
remote:        https://ilovearisti-api.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/ilovearisti-api.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

Next, I type `heroku open` but I get this

[image: heroku screen]

Here is my log

```
2020-09-14T07:49:39.697250+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user ...
2020-09-14T07:49:39.697250+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user ...@gmail.com
2020-09-14T07:49:39.896372+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user ...@gmail.com
2020-09-14T07:49:39.896372+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by ...@gmail.com
2020-09-14T07:49:57.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user ...@gmail.com
2020-09-14T07:50:10.871508+00:00 app[api]: Deploy a43580dd by user ...@gmail.com
2020-09-14T07:50:10.871508+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user ...@gmail.com
2020-09-14T07:50:10.885127+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to web@1:Free by user ...@gmail.com
2020-09-14T07:50:11.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-09-14T07:50:12.954485+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2020-09-14T07:50:15.334557+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-09-14T07:50:15.376733+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-09-14T07:50:15.379585+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-09-14T07:50:17.472619+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2020-09-14T07:50:19.961480+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-09-14T07:50:20.003490+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-09-14T07:57:13.654262+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=ilovearisti-api.herokuapp.com request_id=1dd621a5-49f2-445b-8738-0b378471f8db fwd="176.58.227.122" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-09-14T07:57:14.847978+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=ilovearisti-api.herokuapp.com request_id=332a59b3-a02a-4557-a422-feec336e873b fwd="176.58.227.122" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-09-14T07:57:58.102905+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=ilovearisti-api.herokuapp.com request_id=22c1894c-9243-42f0-af50-e7cee643c78a fwd="176.58.227.122" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-09-14T07:57:59.455823+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=ilovearisti-api.herokuapp.com request_id=c23b7c41-59bb-42aa-bc94-da950aa7987c fwd="176.58.227.122" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-09-14T08:03:50.154269+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=ilovearisti-api.herokuapp.com request_id=29f38dc7-20f3-4e92-8248-2e23adbfe89c fwd="176.58.227.122" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-09-14T08:03:50.545906+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=ilovearisti-api.herokuapp.com request_id=4958d987-0274-4c58-8bb2-38e8f74e9ed0 fwd="176.58.227.122" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

The message in the console log is this

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)
```

I did some research but I couldn't find any solution. I changed the port number to 8080, but still nothing.

Here is my [repo](https://github.com/theo82/iLoveAristi-api).

How can I fix that error? It works fine locally.

Comment: I too am facing this issue since I tried to change my react app to server-side rendered app. Rolling back to client-side version works fine, but not the ssr version. I thought it had something to do with ssr config, but as your app is facing this, it's definitely not regarding the ssr config.